# selective memory bias and the ideal self

Tags: memory

Personal theory is that selective memory bias is a component of bias towards the ideal self.

A person is more likely to remember those things that promote the ideal self while warping or forgetting things that compromise the ideal self.

Does academia know anything about this. im just a normal guy

Comment: Welcome to Psych&Neuro, we ask that questions be [framed in psychology or neuroscience](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/why-was-my-question-closed-as-not-framed-in-psychology-or-neuroscience): we expect questions to be supported by something you've read to contextualize the question.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  You can read about [mnemic neglect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemic_neglect), and see if that helps you formulate a more specific question.